# form button to post data and run script via onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a form that needs to both post data from form and run a script to redirect the page based on the users input from the form.

I have run the script successfully but cannot find a way to post the data from the form. The submit button has to be a `type="button"` or the jscript `onclick="calc()"` will not run. I'm not sure why.

My button code is:

```
<input type="button"  id="calculate" value="Calculate"  onclick="calc()" formaction="carbondata.php" formmethod="post"/>
```

and my script is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function calc() {
    if (document.getElementById('mileage').value == '0-15000' && document.getElementById('gdi').value == 'yes' && document.getElementById('fuel').value == 'yes') {
      window.location = 'http://www.arnolfodesign.com/clients/itw_carbonator/outcome01.html'
    } else if (document.getElementById('mileage').value == '0-15000' && document.getElementById('gdi').value == 'yes' && document.getElementById('fuel').value == 'no') {
      window.location = 'http://www.arnolfodesign.com/clients/itw_carbonator/outcome02.html'
    }
  }
</script>
```

I have a simple php form to send the data to my email but the form does not send. The site is at:
    [carbonator](http://www.arnolfodesign.com/clients/itw_carbonator/autoTest.html)

Can I simply add a `post()` into the script?  I've researched this here and found some very confusing solutions to issues that were somewhat the same but no exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use jQuery ?

If you use jQuery you can simply use `$.post()` function.

Comment: I don't know. Where would I use the $.post()?

Comment: $.post( "myfile.php", {argName: "argValue", arg2Name: "arg2Value" } );

More info here : https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: This is assuming I know jquery, which I do not. Is there anyway to simply add  code to what I have to make it post and send the email?

Comment: Simply include jQuery using <script> HTML tag. Then put the $().post() function inside calc function (assuming it's the function called by the form button). First you have to get the value from the form fields. Using jQuery it would look like : var email = $("#email").val(); assuming that your email field is defined by id="email" in the HTML. Then use post function to send form data to the script, something like : $().post("TheScript.php", {email : email}); Btw you should learn jQuery. It's really easy, cross platform and better than Ajax

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'll try to implement this.  Placing the post function inside the calc function was something I tried earlier with no results. However I may have not written the code correctly. I have a pretty long string of javascript if/then statement and I'm not a real jscript coder so this is gonna be hit or miss.

Comment: So the resulting script looks like...   `<script type="text/javascript">
function calc() {
 if (document.getElementById('mileage').value == '0-15000' && document.getElementById('gdi').value == 'yes' && document.getElementById('fuel').value == 'yes') {
 var car = $("#car-years" , "#car-makes" , "#car-models" , "#gdi" , "#fuel" , "#mileage").val(); 
$().post("carbondata.php", {car : car}); 
 window.location = 'http://www.arnolfodesign.com/clients/itw_carbonator/outcome01.html'
  } else if (...`

Comment: @Arnolfo yeah something like this! But don't forget to include jQuery lib before

Answer (score 0):

I could not get jquery .post() function to post  and redirect user. However, I was able to do both within the post.php page.

added the redirect with php.

```
 if ($mileage == "0-15000" && $gdi == "yes" && $fuel == "yes")  {
header("Location:http://www.arnolfodesign.com/clients/itw_carbonator/outcome01.html");
 } elseif ($mileage == "0-15000" && $gdi == "yes" && $fuel == "no") {
  header("Location:http://www.arnolfodesign.com/clients/itw_carbonator/outcome02.html");
 } elseif ($mileage == "0-15000" && $gdi == "no" && $fuel == "yes") {
 header("Location:http://www.arnolfodesign.com/clients/itw_carbonator/outcome01.html");
 } elseif ($mileage == "0-15000" && $gdi == "no" && $fuel == "no") {
header("Location:http://www.arnolfodesign.com/clients/itw_carbonator/outcome02.html");
```

This hopefully works just as well.